# How to extract facebook comments from newsarticle website using nodejs

Tags: json, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract facebook comments from newsarticle website. for example, I want to extract comments from the link 
http://therealsingapore.com/content/16-year-old-schoolboy-had-sex-3-underage-girls.
Using the graph api from facebook, here is the result:
http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://therealsingapore.com/content/16-year-old-schoolboy-had-sex-3-underage-girls.

I would like to extract the comments using nodejs. I have used one open source module called request to get the result as an http object

Here is my code: I use JSON.parse to convert the string into a JSON Obj. However, I failed to get attributes such as id or message from the parsedResponse variable. Can anyone tell me where went wrong? Or is there a better way to get facebook comments with nodejs? Thank you!

```
var http = require('http');


var url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://therealsingapore.com/content/16-year-old-schoolboy-had-sex-3-underage-girls';

var request = require('request');
var counter = 0;

request(url, function (error, response, body) {

if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

  var  parsedResponse = JSON.parse(body);
}
console.log(parsedResponse);
var msg = parsedResponse.comments.data[0].message;
console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: Well, the result is actually really empty, because the query is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is IMHO only possible if you use the Batch API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#operations) like this:

```
curl \
   -F 'access_token={your_app_access_token}' \
   -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-id","relative_url":"v2.1/?ids=http://therealsingapore.com/content/16-year-old-schoolboy-had-sex-3-underage-girls",},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"{result=get-id:$.*.og_object.id}/comments?limit=500"}]' \
   https://graph.facebook.com/
```

In Node, this would equivalent in

```
var request = require('request');
var app_access_token = "{your_app_access_token}";

request({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com",
    body: "access_token="+app_access_token+"&batch="+JSON.stringify([{ "method":"GET","name":"get-id","relative_url":"/v2.1/?ids=http://therealsingapore.com/content/16-year-old-schoolboy-had-sex-3-underage-girls",},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"/{result=get-id:$.*.og_object.id}/comments?limit=500"}]),
    method: "POST"
}, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(parsedResponse);

    }

});
```

You need to replace `{your_app_access_token}` with a real App Access Token.

Comment: thank you for answering that！I will go and try it out tmr. But I have to tell you that the result is not empty. When I print the obj in string, it has everything I need.

Comment: The data array is empty: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=comments%2F%3Fids%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Ftherealsingapore.com%2Fcontent%2F16-year-old-schoolboy-had-sex-3-underage-girls&version=v2.1